# Why does this prepared statement with like doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a select statement to get some data from my mysql server. I wanna find some keywords for e.g. c in a list like this a,b,c,d,e,f that is stored under the tags column on the mysql server. My question is why this code won't work?

```
    if(isset($_GET['TAG'])){
        $type="tags";
        $content = '%'.$_GET['TAG'].'%';
    }
    
    
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE ? LIKE ? ORDER BY `timerec` DESC;";
    $s=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $s->execute(array($type, $content));
    $data=$s->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
```

The variable dbh is the pdo that I will not post here cause it is 100% working and contain sensible information.
The $_GET['TAG'] can contain a keyword.
Please do not correct any security risks in this code if there are any, I just want to know what is wrong with the following code.

Comment: You can't use parameters for column names.

Comment: @Sharky So I will have to enter that manually in the sql query  with variable or similar right?

Comment: @Sharky Ok thx solved it!